# recursively file delete from directory in perl

Tags: perl, window

I am new in perl script. I want to write perl which delete previous backup file and extract new backup file from dropbox and rename with specific file name.

Example:

backup location:

`D:\Database\store_name\`  containing `.bak` files

Actual folder data 
`D:\Database\Mahavir Dhanya Bhandar\` contain `.bak` file

`D:\Database\Patel General Store\` containg `.bak` files

..so on

1. How can write perl script code which delete `*.bak` files store_recursively
   2.extract new backup file from dropbox and rename with specific file name.

Comment: Have a look at [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into walking your file tree. http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively. Combine this with simple file operations (copying, deleting, etc.) and you should be good.

```
use File::Find qw(find);

my $dir = "D:\Database\Store_Name";

find sub {unlink $File::Find::name if /\.bak$/}, $dir;
```

and assuming that `connectToDropbox()` connects to your dropbox

```
use File::Copy;
use File::Find qw(find);

my $backup = connectToDropbox();
my $dir = "D\Database\Store_Name";

find sub {copy($backup -> getFile("file"), "newFile")} $dir;
```

of course, this assumes that you already can set up a connection and such to Dropbox. If not, there is a good CPAN library[here](http://search.cpan.org/~nfokz/File-Dropbox-0.6/lib/File/Dropbox.pm) you can check out.